# How do I read the data of different files into an array?

Tags: java, file

I have a folder that contains only integer files. User input writes the files so the number of files in the folder always changes.

Here is my code.

```
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt");
       fw.write(2);

       FileWriter fz = new FileWriter("test2.txt");
       fz.write(3);

       File folder= new File("folder");
       folder.mkdir();

       // Returns an array of pathnames of all files in a folder. 
       File[] fileArray = folder.listFiles();

       // For each file in the file array
       for ( File file : fileArray){


          int i;

           // Reads each file.
           FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

           for ( i = 0 ; i > fileArray.length ; i++) {
               int[] anArray = new int[i];
               anArray[i] = fr.read();
               System.out.println(anArray[i]);
           }
```

I want the FileReader to read the data into anArray. I cannot code the files individually like this,

```
anArray[0] = fr.read();
anArray[1] = fr.read();
```

because the number of files always changes. How do I do this?

Comment: What about making use of  `fileArray.length` ?

Comment: @Harvtronix I already tried that, it does not seem to be reading the array. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: In your above code, you have a greater than sign in your for loop. It should be a less than sign

Comment: It's working now. I used ArrayList and changed greater than to less than sign. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to have `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` containing file contents.

For example:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> allFilesContents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for ( File file : fileArray){
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
       String lineRead = null;
       while((lineRead=br.readLine())!=null){
         fileContents.add(lineRead);
       }
       allFilesContents.add(fileContents);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a best way to loop through folder and file. I also tried something like this before:

```
  for (File file : fileArray){
       // Reads each file.
       FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

       int length=(int) file.length();
       char anArray[] = new char[length];
       fr.read(anArray);
               for(char c: anArray){
            System.out.print(c);
               }
       }
```